# is there IntelliJ extension guidelines? around navigations (ex. explorer, search, menu, etc) so that a custom extension can be discovered intuitively

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, intellij-plugin

There would be more than 10 different ways a developer can leverage a functionality on the IDE (explorer, menu, submenu, shortcut, search, etc)
is there any guidelines on IDE extensions such that custom extensions can follow? such that custom extension capabilities can be discovered and consumed easily.

tried with couple of navigational elements but i think i am missing larger context when designing the IDE navigational aspects

Comment: Please see the following part from IntelliJ Platform SDK - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/user-interface-components.html. If you have some specific questions about creating plugins, do not hesitate to raise a new issue at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development to discuss it with the IDEA team directly.